# Splunk query filter out based on other event in same index

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a index named `Events`

It contains a bunch of different events, all events have a property called `EventName`.
Now I want to do a query where I return everything that matches the following:

IF AccountId exists in event with EventName `AccountCreated` AND there is at least 1 event with EventName `FavoriteCreated` with the same AccountId -> return all events where EventName == `AccountCreated`

Example events:

**AccountCreated**

```
{
   "AccountId": 1234,
   "EventName": "AccountCreated",
   "SomeOtherProperty": "Some value",
   "Brand": "My Brand",
   "DeviceType": "Mobile",
   "EventTime": "2020-06-01T12:13:14Z"
}
```

**FavoriteCreated**

```
{
   "AccountId": 1234,
   "EventName": "FavoritesCreated,
   "Brand": "My Brand",
   "DeviceType": "Mobile",
   "EventTime": "2020-06-01T12:13:14Z"
}
```

Given the following two events, I would like to create 1 query that returns the AccountCreated event.

I've tried the following but it does not work, surely I must be missing something simple?

```
index=events EventName=AccountCreated 
  [search index=events EventName=FavoriteCreated | dedup AccountId | fields AccountId]
| table AccountId, SomeOtherProperty
```

Im expecting ~6000 hits here but Im only getting 2298 events. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
Based on the answer given by @warren below, the following query works. The only problem is that it's using a JOIN which limits us to 50K results from the subsearch. When running this query I get 5900 results in total = Correct.

```
index=events EventName=AccountCreated AccountId=*
| stats count by AccountId, EventName
| fields - count
| join AccountId 
    [ | search index=events EventName=FavoriteCreated AccountId=*
    | stats count by AccountId ]
| fields - count
| table AccountId, EventName
```

I then tried to use his updated example like this but the problem seems to be that it returns FavoriteCreated events instead of AccountCreated. 
When running this query I get 25 494 hits = Incorrect.

```
index=events AccountId=* (EventName=AccountCreated OR EventName=FavoriteCreated)
| stats values(EventName) as EventName by AccountId
| eval EventName=mvindex(EventName,-1)
| search EventName="FavoriteCreated"
| table AccountId, EventName
```

**Update 2 - WORKING**
@warren is awesome, here is a full working query that only returns data from the AccountCreated events IF 1 or more FavoriteCreated event exists.

```
index=events AccountId=* (EventName=AccountCreated OR EventName=FavoriteCreated)
| stats 
    values(Brand) as Brand,
    values(DeviceType) as DeviceType,
    values(Email) as Email,
    values(EventName) as EventName
    values(EventTime) as EventTime,
    values(Locale) as Locale,
    values(ClientIp) as ClientIp
  by AccountId
| where mvcount(EventName)>1
| eval EventName=mvindex(EventName,0)
| eval EventTime=mvindex(EventTime,0)
| eval ClientIp=mvindex(ClientIp,0)
| eval DeviceType=mvindex(DeviceType,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found, perhaps, [one factor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62063023/4418) of your issues - that [subsearches](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/Latest/SearchTutorial/Useasubsearch) are capped at [50,000](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.4/SearchReference/Join#Usage) (when doing a `join`) events (or 60 seconds run time (or [10,000](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/Latest/Admin/limitsconf#.5Bsubsearch.5D) results when you use a "normal" subsearch)).

Start by dumping `dedup` in favor of `stats`:

```
index=events EventName=AccountCreated AccountId=*
| stats count by AccountId, SomeOtherProperty [, more, fields, as, desired]
| fields - count
| search 
    [ | search index=events EventName=FavoriteCreated AccountId=*
    | stats count by AccountId 
    | fields - count]
<rest of search>
```

If that doesn't get you where you want to be (ie, you *still* have too many results in your subsearch), you can try `join`:

```
index=events EventName=AccountCreated AccountId=*
| stats count by AccountId, SomeOtherProperty [, more, fields, as, desired]
| fields - count
| join AccountId 
    [ | search index=events EventName=FavoriteCreated AccountId=*
    | stats count by AccountId ]
| fields - count
<rest of search>
```

There *are* yet more ways of doing what you're looking for - but these two should get you a long ways toward your goal

Here's a `join`-less approach which'll show only "FavoriteCreated" events:

```
index=events AccountId=* (EventName=AccountCreated OR EventName=FavoriteCreated)
| stats values(EventName) as EventName values(SomeOtherProperty) as SomeOtherProperty by AccountId
| eval EventName=mvindex(EventName,-1)
| search EventName="FavoriteCreated"
```

And here's one that shows "FavoriteCreated" *only* if there was also an "AccountCreated" event in the same timeframe:

```
index=events AccountId=* (EventName=AccountCreated OR EventName=FavoriteCreated)
| stats values(EventName) as EventName values(SomeOtherProperty) as SomeOtherProperty by AccountId
| where mvcount(EventName)>1
```

And if you want to 'pretend' the `values()` didn't happen (ie, throw-out the "favoriteCreated" entry), add this:

```
| eval EventName=mvindex(EventName,0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, will try this out first thing in the morning!! :)

Comment: I tried it now, the first one "did not work" (same problem as before with truncated result). However, the second one worked like a charm!! Thank you!

Comment: When using the join, am I correct in my assumption that I've only raised the limit of records returned by the subsearch from 10000 to 50000?

Comment: @JOSEFtw - yes (note docs.splunk links provided). With a better picture of your use case, we may be able to give you an even better (and `join`-less) answer, too :)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I missed them! So I can give you my full use case here. Let's say that I have 10 million FavoriteCreated events and 10 million AccountCreated events. I need to be able to select all AccountCreated events where the user has at least 1 FavoriteCreated event during a specific time period (let's say past six months just to give you an idea of the data size). Do you need anymore details?

Comment: Basically we use that information to decide if a user has been active or not during the last 6 months. And since the data returned from the subsearch can be a lot bigger than 50K I think you understand my problem? A join will not work Im afraid...

Comment: @JOSEFtw - try the additional search option I've provided

Comment: thank you so much for your time and help. I've updated my question with examples on the queries I ran after your suggestions, the last one without the JOIN does not seem to work, it seems like it returns FavoriteCreated events instead of AccountCreated. Maybe it's something really small I need to change? This is my first day working with Splunk so please bare with me... :)

Comment: @JOSEFtw - the last one is *supposed* to only return "FavoriteCreated" events: that's what you said you wanted to find :)  ...I've added another option below that for you, too

Comment: Ah sorry, maybe im bad at expressing myself. Basically: I want to get ALL AccountCreated events WHERE at least 1 FavoriteCreated event exists with the same AccountId as the AccountCreated event! :) I want the exact same result as the JOIN query you posted, but without the join!

Comment: @JOSEFtw - did you try the `join`less search at the end?

Comment: Yes I did! The problem with that one is that it returns FavoriteCreated events. I want it to return AccountCreated events :) IF AccountCreated event exists AND at least 1 FavoriteCreated event exists -> return said AccountCreated event :)

Comment: @JOSEFtw - then it *sounds* like you *didn't* try the `join`-less search listed at the end: the one that only returns events that have **both** FavoriteCreated ***and*** AccountCreated events :)

Comment: I DID run it! And it works...BUT ( :) )...it's combining the values, so instead of getting just the AccountCreated event data I get a combined row of both the AccountCreated and FavoriteCreated event. Do you know if I can filter that somehow to just contain the data from AccountCreated? Thank you so much for your time/help! :)

Comment: @JOSEFtw - it's only combining the values of one field ... just add this line after the `|where`: `| eval EventName=mvindex(EventName,0)`

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I updated my question with a working query at the bottom! You see the filtering I do at the end, is it possible to do that for "all fields"? Something like ```| eval *=mvindex(*,0)```? Or do I always need to specify eacg field explicitly?

Comment: @JOSEFtw - why would you filter on anything ***but*** `EventName`? The only field which will "have FavoriteCreated" data in it is `EventName`

Comment: no that's not correct. For example the field EventTime exists in both AccountCreated and FavoriteCreated. If I have 1 AccountCreated and 4 FavoriteCreated for 1 specific AccountId, EventTime will contain 5 values. When I then add eval EventTime=mvindex(EventTime,0), I only get 1 value (the one from AccountCreated)

Comment: @JOSEFtw - that's additional data you hadn't shared earlier :)

Comment: Yeah sorry I updated my question when I discovered it. But thank you so much for your help, it's working now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Splunk truncates the SubSearch result if its bigger than 10 000 results...
[image: Splunk search feedback]
[image]